# URLSessionConfiguration's httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost not working in iOS 10?

Tags: ios10, nsurlsessionconfiguration, urlsession

Setting this parameter doesn't affect the number of
simultaneous connections to a host. I've found the same issue on [apple developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/73565). It looks like a bug in iOS 10, iOS 9 works properly.

```
let sessionConfiguration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: <identifier>)
    sessionConfiguration.httpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 4
    sessionConfiguration.allowsCellularAccess = AppDelegate.shared.userDefaults.allowsCellularAccess
    sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 7*60
    sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 24*60*60
    let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate:self, delegateQueue: operationQueue)
```

Does anybody have the same problem?
If there an alternative stable way to manage a queue of many uploads/downloads in background?

Comment: have the same problem, but btw: your timeout interval 7*60 is destructive long